# Entity Framework - localized entity -best solution?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im working on ASP.NET vNext project with EF7 localization. I have some idea how provide localized data which will be stored in database. Please, what is the best SOLUTION? A, B or C? or exist some better?

SOLUTION A:

```
public  class BaseEntity 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public BaseEntityModel()
    {
        this.Id = new Guid();
    }

    [Required]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BaseEntity> Translations { get; set; }

}      

public class Language
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8)]
    public string Code { get; set; } // Unique
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

SOLUTION B:
(use composite key - RowId and languageID) like this...

```
public  class BaseEntity 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public BaseEntityModel()
    {
        this.Id = new Guid();
    }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid LanguageId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

SOLUTION C: 
Is used by NopCommerce. Nop can create for each property static resource with key + language + value. This resources are cached. Row in table contain key to resource file. Can this implementation cause lower speed?

Comment: Just curious - why you would use database to store localized data? In my opinion your DB should be culture neutral as much as possible, that's why we have resource files. Take into consideration that sesource files are cached so once accessed, perf impact can be neglected.

Comment: Thank you, I will use solution C

Comment: Just to clarify - storing translations in DB isn't bad. Just have in mind that if you have small system, you have something out of the box called resources.  If you have bigger system, storing translations in DB will sooner than later become difficult and problematic.

Comment: I will build modular CMS. I see now nop architecture. BlogPost use in entity LanguageId and  public virtual Langugage language..... So each row in this table is localized with one-to many to Langugage Table... This provide localized version of strings in row. You can query with language parameter. Resources are used for validation messages, column description etc.. ?? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I would say c is the best solution. Nopcommerce has done it the best way by keeping it loosely coupled.